# Assign property value doesn't work in Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My query is:

```
db.Room.find({}, function (err, rooms) {
  if (!err) {
    async.each(rooms, function (room, done) {
      db.User.find({}, function (err, users) {
        if (err) {
          done(err)
        } else {
          room.users = users
          room._name = room.name
          done()
        }
      })
    }, function (err) {
      if (!err) {
        socket.emit('read:rooms', rooms)
      }
    })
  }
})
```

and schemas are:

room:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
var Schema = mongoose.Schema,
  ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

var Room = new Schema({
  name: String
});

module.exports = Room
```

user:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
var Schema = mongoose.Schema,
  ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

var User = new Schema({
  email: String
});

module.exports = User
```

but in front-end:

```
  socket.on('read:rooms', function (rooms) {
    $scope.rooms = rooms
  })
```

but `rooms` has no `users` property, help me, please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because the `Rooms` schema doesn't have a `users` property.

So, there are a few ways to fix it. Since it looks like though you want the `users` property to be something that really isn't part of the schema, and is a client-side join rather than work that is done on the database (which is a good!), I'd suggest you convert the data to be just plain old JavaScript objects when you send it over the socket (this would have happened anyway, you're just doing it a bit earlier).

So, when the `find` returns, it is actually returning a fully-realized MongooseJS model object. While you can set dynamic properties on the object instance, they aren't part of the "data" of the model, so that when it is serialized later to the client, only the properties that are documented will be available.

So, here is an example of what I'd suggest:

```
db.Room.find({}, function (err, rooms) {
  if (!err) {
    var oRooms = [];
    async.each(rooms, function (room, done) {
      /* etc. your code */

       } else {
          var oRoom = room.toObject();
          oRoom.users = users
          oRoom._name = room.name
          oRooms.push(oRoom);
          done()
       }
```

This technique would use the `toObject` [functionality](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toObject) of a Model to return a JavaScript object (not a Mongoose model). That way, you can do what you'd like to the object, including adding new properties dynamically.

Later, of course, make sure you send the new array of rooms to the client:

```
 if (!err) {
    socket.emit('read:rooms', oRooms)
 }
```